# How to control custom object through territory management?

Tags: custom-object, security, territory-management, territory

I have 2 custom objects and tabs. Accounts and Users are assigned manually in my org. How to I control their visibility/security according to territories?

Are there any samples that I refer to? That would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: If the custom object is detail of Account visibility will be automatically controlled as per Account

Comment: @MohithShrivastava So if my custom object has a lookup to Account, visibility cannot be controlled by territory only by MD relation?

Comment: I am not so sure of it but you may do a quick POC to see how it works .I guess it should work with MD for sure but with lookup you may need some custom code .But not sure

Comment: Thanks, so no standard way of controlling visibility only custom coding?

Comment: Also, I already have lookup relationship to Account from the 2 custom objects. If I create a new MD relationship for each of the custom object, will that work? Little confused.